# Selenium Page Model - How to get an attribute, extract its content and use it in another class

Tags: java, selenium, attributes, pageobjects, page-factory

I would like to know if it's possible to get the content of an attribute located in the DOM and store it as a variable in a java class (a class that corresponds to a page in a website as per the POM approach) using PageFactory from Selenium (@FindBy).
Then, I would need to use this variable in another class that corresponds to another page on the same website (Page Object Model).
Are there some examples and method to do someone can provide?
I don't have any code to present. I was just wondering if it's technically possible and how.

----**EDIT 1**----
As requested, some code to explain.
Below is the attribute in the DOM

```html
<label id="HouseNumberVersion">HOUSE N° x </label>
```

For example i find this element of the DOM using PageFactory from Selenium and get its content; following POM approach ( that's why it's called Page1 )

```java
    
public class Page1 {  

 WebDriver driver;
   
 @FindBy (xpath="//*[@id="HouseNumberVersion"]")
   WebElement houseNumber;
  
 public Page1(WebDriver driver){
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    this.driver = driver;
 }

 public Page1(){
}

 public void assertEquals(){
   String actual = houseNumber.getAttribute("innerHTML");
   //some code here to assert this is equal
   // to another string but not this method is not needed it's just to show that
   // i can use this string in this page properly using this method
 }
 
 public String getHouse(){
  String actual = houseNumber.getAttribute("innerHTML");
  return actual;
}
    
}
```

Now i would like to call and use the string `actual` in my other class , which corresponds to another page in the website so.

```java
public class Page2 {  

 WebDriver driver;
 
 //i search for an element in this second page which is an input  
 @FindBy (xpath="//*[@id="HouseInput"]")
     WebElement houseInput;
 
 public Page2(WebDriver driver){
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    this.driver = driver;
 }

 public void sendActualToInput(){
   
  // i created an object to recover the string within the return method in
  // Page1
  Page1 p = new Page1();
  String number = p.getHouse(); 
  //i send this string recovered from the other 
  // to another string
  houseInput.sendKeys(number);
 }
    
}
```

And i call finally the method `sendActualToInput` from Page2 in my main Test script as follows

```java
public class MyTest (){

 public WebDriver driver;
 // some Before Method here ..

 @Test
 Public  void CheckHouse(){
  Page2 p2Object = new Page2(driver);
  p2Object.sendActualToInput();
  //some others actions here..
 }

}
```

I tried that but i got the error `java.lang.NullPointerException`. The Eclipse console is reffering to the line `String actual = houseNumber.getAttribute("innerHTML");`
It seems that nothing is returned to the `sendActualToInput`method in Page2. Because if i put a sysout in this method `sendActualToInput` it print the content of this sysout in the console.

Is it manageable?

------**EDIT2**--------

I've initialized my fields in my code. I just forgot to add them in the snippet but now Initialization functions are in the code. And issue is still happenning.

Comment: Can you show what would you expect in pseudo-code? That is really hard to get your use case.

Comment: It's done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `NullPointerException` because your fields are not itintialized.

Here:

```java
 public void sendActualToInput(){
   
  // i created an object to recover the string within the return method in
  // Page1
  Page1 p = new Page();
  String number = p.getHouse(); 
  //i send this string recovered from the other 
  // to another string
  houseInput.sendKeys(number);
 }
```

When you're doing `Page1 p = new Page();` it creates an object where all fields are `null`. In order to initialize them you need to use `PageFactory.initElements(...)`

So in your case you need something like:

```
public class Page1 {  

 @FindBy (xpath="//*[@id="HouseNumberVersion"]")
   WebElement houseNumber;

 public void assertEquals(){
   String actual = houseNumber.getAttribute("innerHTML");
   //some code here to assert this is equal
   // to another string but not this method is not needed it's just to show that
   // i can use this string in this page properly using this method
 }
 
 public String getHouse(){
  String actual = houseNumber.getAttribute("innerHTML");
  return actual;
 }

 public Page1(WebDriver driver){
   PageFactory.init(driver, this)
 }
    
}
```

You need to update your second page correspondingly:

```
public class Page2 {  

 WebDriver driver;
 
 //i search for an element in this second page which is an input  
 @FindBy (xpath="//*[@id="HouseInput"]")
     WebElement houseInput;

 public Page2(WebDriver driver){
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    this.driver = driver;
 }

 public void sendActualToInput(){
   
  // i created an object to recover the string within the return method in
  // Page1
  Page1 p = new Page(driver);
  String number = p.getHouse(); 
  //i send this string recovered from the other 
  // to another string
  houseInput.sendKeys(number);
 }
    
}
```

```
public class MyTest (){

 public WebDriver driver;
 // some Before Method here ..

 @Test
 Public  void CheckHouse(){
  Page2 p2Object = new Page2(driver);
  p2Object.sendActualToInput();
  //some others actions here..
 }

}
```

So that now you initialize your page2 against your driver and pass the same driver to page1 constructor.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention but i alerady initialized my fields  . So initialization is not the issue !

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code where you get NullPointer. We'll find the solution for you.

Comment: Many thanks. I did a proper update. All is in the post now!

Comment: `Page1 p = new Page();` this does not get driver reference to the constructor

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Your code in example still looks inconsistent. You're saying that you still get NPE (that means you have some real implementation of your attempt). I'm asking you to add your that real trial where you get NPE.

Comment: This ` Page1 p = new Page();` won't event be compiled because you do not have `Page` class. `Page1` constructor expects `WebDriver` but in this line of your example you do not pass it..

Comment: Sorry it's there now. Exactly as i put it in my code. Again Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228004/discussion-between-chaoui05-and-alexey-r).